# Simple Rails 3.2 app + RefineryCMS + devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, refinerycms

I had a simple Rails 3.2 app and later added RefineryCMS by following the official guide (http://refinerycms.com/guides/with-an-existing-rails-app). Now I want to add devise to the Rails app to restrict public content based in the logged in user.

I know that there is an official RefineryCMS guide about adding RefineryCMS to existing Rails app + devise (http://refinerycms.com/guides/with-an-existing-rails-31-devise-app), but my scenario is different as in my case now devise is to be added. Any specific steps that I need to keep in mind. It would be good if someone can point me to a tutorial. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the procedure in the guide http://refinerycms.com/guides/with-an-existing-rails-31-devise-app.

There were errors

- undifined method 'new_refinery_user_registeration_path' and on refresh
- uninitialized constant Refinery::Role

and for that I had to replace ::Refinery::Role to ::Role in user model and override refinery_user_required? and just installed? in lib/refinery/refinery_patch.rb

```
def refinery_user_required?
  false
end

def just_installed?
 false
end
```

Comment: This implementation was specific to my development environment.